# I want to echo multi-dimensional array by using foreach loop

Tags: php

```
<?php


$StudScore = array( 
    "Mary" => array(
        "physics" => 35,        
        "maths" => 30,      
        "chemistry" => 39       
    ),
    "Tom" => array(
        "physics" => 30,
        "maths" => 32,
        "chemistry" => 29
    ),
    "Jon" => array(
        "physics" => 31,
        "maths" => 22,
        "chemistry" => 39
    )
);


foreach ($StudScore as $key => $value) {
            echo "<li>$key</li>";
            if (is_array($value)) {
                echo "<ul>";
                echoArray($value);
                echo "</ul>";
            } else {
                echo "<ul><li>$value</li></ul>";
            }
        }
?>
```

Till now i have tried to print array but i am getting below error kindly help me out with this .

**Output :
Mary
Fatal error: Call to undefined function echoArray()**

i want it to be print as example:

Mary = physics:35,maths:30,chemistry:39

Tom = physics:30,maths:32,chemistry:29

Jon = physics:31,maths:22,chemistry:39

Comment: Is `echoArray()` a custom function of yours that you forgot to include maybe? Other than that, like the error said: `echoArray()` does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

It has to be either `echo var_dump($value);` or `echo print_r($value);` if you want to print the WHOLE array. There is no function called `echoArray()` in PHP.

When you only want to print ONE key/value from the array, you also have to use `echo $value;`, since the keys/values are only strings.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: No need to `echo` a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` (unless you use the `return` parameter) though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach ($StudScore as $name => $value) {
        echo $name." = ";
        foreach ($value as $subject => $marks) {
            echo $subject.":".$marks.",";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Finally i got my answer it give output like :

Mary = physics:35,maths:30,chemistry:39

Tom = physics:30,maths:32,chemistry:29

Jon = physics:31,maths:22,chemistry:39